# Is it possible to isolate an AngularJS module from the rest?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a main app module and this should have children modules, but I don't want these children to use services or components from the others, I want them totally isolated because they will behave like sub-apps.

```
AppModule
   - ModuleA
   - ModuleB
```

For example, in the next Plunker, I want to have a privateService in moduleA not accesible by moduleB.

https://plnkr.co/edit/PewaB7kGZp2I6XCxPMW9?p=preview

How can I do it? Can I continue using **ui-router** with it?

Comment: This is what the modules are for. Please, explain the difficulties you have with this approach. The answer 'It is possible' is too short to be allowed to be posted (and has very little value, by the way).

Comment: If I have a parent app that injects two other modules, for example, **moduleA** and **moduleB**, moduleA can use all the moduleB services and components and that is what I want to prevent.

Comment: If moduleA depends on moduleB units, moduleB should be loaded it as a dependency in moduleA. If moduleA uses some of moduleB units but not all, the units should be separated into common module which is loaded by both moduleA and moduleB.

Comment: Precisely that is what I want to prevent, I don't want moduleA to access all components of moduleB and vice versa.

Comment: Please, explain your case in the question. It is not obvious why you want to prevent it. There's no such rule as 'modules shouldn't depend on each other'. Because, again, this is what the modules are for!

Comment: I made a Plunker, hope that helps to clarify the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The demarcation between modules (sharedModule, privateModuleA, privateModuleB) is semantic.

The module (e.g. privateModuleA) shouldn't use units from another module (e.g. privateModuleB) if the latter module isn't listed as a dependency of the former. Doing the opposite can be considered a bad practice and just should be avoided.

As opposed to Angular 2 which has [a hierarchy of injectors](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/hierarchical-dependency-injection.html), AngularJS has a single injector per app. Once module is loaded, its units are available in other modules that are loaded in this injector instance. This is the expected  behaviour that cannot be changed.